# loading indicator based on service returning observable

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

this can be lame question but I'm new to angular and I don't know much about those observables.

I got some code where options of second select are depending on first select value. There is a refreshPeople() method which is called on first select change, and this method is tryging to set loading to true, then make async call for data, and then set loading to false.

But the last command in refreshPeople() is not waiting for async call to end. :(

What is the proper way to make those kind of things in angular2+?

So the template is:

```
Gender: {{gender}}

<ng-select 
  [items]="genders" 
  (change)="refreshPeople()" 
  [(ngModel)]="gender"
  >
</ng-select>

<br/>

<ng-select 
  [items]="people$ | async" 
  bindLabel="name" 
  [loading]="loading" 
  bindValue="id"
  >
</ng-select>

People loading: {{loading}}
```

Component code:

```
  people$: Observable<Person[]>;
  gender = 'male';
  loading = true;
  genders = ['male', 'female'];

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.people$ = this.dataService.getPeopleByGender(this.gender);
    this.loading = false;
  }

  async refreshPeople(): any {
      this.loading = true;
      this.people$ = await this.dataService.getPeopleByGender(this.gender);
      this.loading = false;
  }
```

And the service method:

```
  getPeopleByGender(gender: string = 'male'): Observable<Person[]> {
    let items = getMockPeople();
    items = items.filter(x => x.gender === gender);
    return of(items).pipe(delay(2000));
  }
```

Demo is here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/async-select-options-with-filter?file=null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed your code on stackblitz so it works as expected.

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/async-select-options-with-filter-mgpkst)

your code has 2 main issues:

1. You can't await observable execution. Only promises. Observables are a layer built over promises to extend their functionality and add more features.
2. An observable is only executed after you call **subscribe** on it, which you didn't do.

I highly recommend that you find time to go over the basics of RxJs so you don't face conceptual issues. I made a mistake when I started working with angular by not doing that.

Edit:

```
await this.dataService.getPeopleByGender(this.gender);
```

Here await basically does nothing because your method returns and observalble, it doesn't subscribe to it, so the operation is not asynchronous.

Using the async pipe in your template subscribes to the obervable, but it doesn't allow you to listen to when it finishes execution.